# Can I embed a Swing or SWT component into JavaFx2.0?

Tags: java, swing, swt, javafx-2

everyone! I am in trouble again. When I am working with the IP Camera, I met a big problem, that is, when I use JavaFx Component (ImageView) to show the image tranfered from IP Camera, the picture showing in the imageview is not fluent and smooth, it becomes blank frequently, no matter how I try. But before I use Javafx 2.0 to rebuild the project, I have finished IP Camera part with Swing and SWT Compont, so I was wondering whether I can embed a Swing or SWT compont into JavaFx2.0, it is much better if you know how to show pictures from IP Camera using Javafx2.0.Thanks all.Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 3):

No, the new JavaFx 2 is incompatible with Swing/AWT and there's no official support to embed a Swing component inside .

However seems that the [ThingsFX](http://thingsfx.com/) team is working on [project](http://rkennke.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/embedding-swing-components-within-javafx-2-scenes/) that is a kind of hack to embed a Swing component into an FX Scene .

For the moment nothing although ...